# Как прописать на JS скачивание картинок в статье по кнопке, появляющейся при наведении

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть сайт сток картинок. Изображения разбиты по категориям и так называемым статьям https://funpicts.ru, развернут на wordpress.
Необходимо реализовать: наводим на картинку - появляется кнопка скачать картинку - при клике происходит загрузка.
Нашла код:

```
<button data-download_img="URL_IMG">Скачать</button>

// функция скачивания изображения
function download_img(url){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.target = "_blank";
    link.download = "img.jpg";
    link.href = url;
    link.click();
}
// ловим нажатие кнопки с атрибутом download_img
$("[data-download_img]").click(function(){
    var url=$(this).attr('data-download_img');
    download_img(url);
});
```

Но как сделать, чтобы скачивалась картинка, на которую навели, если имена у них абсолютно разные?
Или может кто плагин для вордпресс знает под эту задачу?

Comment: В первой строке вместо URL_IMG ты должна вставлять url этой картинки. Тогда все заработает.

Comment: @Organizer Ну это очевидно само собой. Только вот в статье допустим 10 картинок, если я напишу мертвый урл - будет только одна скачиваться, а мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на каждую можно было скачать конкретно ту на которую навели.

Answer (score 0):

В твой div post-card добавь кнопочку, `<div class = "download_btn">Скачать</div>` и тогда скриптами можно будет дойти до картиночки как-то так:

```
$(".download_btn").click(function(){
    var url=$(this).parent().find('img').attr('srс');
    download_img(url);
});
```

Comment: Или в post-card__thumbnail можешь кнопочку добавить, как тебе удобнее, главное чтобы в родителе кнопки лежала картинка (неважно как глубоко)